# Possible to do MouseMove actions with PostMessage without hijacking the cursor?

Tags: c#, c++

I am performing MouseClick actions by using PostMessage WinApi, is there any way to simulate MouseMove with it too **without any need of window focus so I can still use my cursor for other tasks?** I am aware of the lParam parameter of PostMessage but it only takes effect when I set my mouse pointer inside of the DirectX window.

SetCursorPos is not the solution as I want to perform MouseMoves without hijacking the cursor.

I hope that makes sense,
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that posting `WM_MOUSEMOVE` / `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` doesn't help?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of places more than `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message `lParam`.

There is `GetMessagePos` function. It can be faked by setting Windows Hooks and altering `MSG::pt`, so call to `GetMessagePos` will return simulated cursor position instead of actual.

But there is `GetCursorPos`, and probably some other ways to get mouse position, like `WM_INPUT`. I think that ultimately only moving cursor (by `SetCursorPos` or by `SendInput`) could cover most of them.