# Python win32gui get current position of the virtual cursor in a window

Tags: python, winapi, postmessage, win32gui, win32con

I know that using `win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, wParam, lParam)` I can fake mouse movement to an unfocused application, without effecting my real mouse.

How can I get my current "fake mouse" position if `win32api.GetCursorPos()` returns the position of my real mouse cursor?

Edit #1:

I am using `WM_MOUSEMOVE` on an **external** application, thus the only thing I have is the application's `window handle` (HWND).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GetMessagePos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagepos):

> Retrieves the cursor position for the last message retrieved by the
> `GetMessage` function.

More reference: [Possible to do MouseMove actions with PostMessage without hijacking the cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61293947/possible-to-do-mousemove-actions-with-postmessage-without-hijacking-the-cursor)

**Edit**

If you only want to get its messages through the HWND of the external application, you need to use [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) and make it into a dll to inject it into the external process.

You can use [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) function, with [`WH_CALLWNDPROC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw#parameters) or some other type of hook, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/winmsg/using-hooks#monitoring-system-events) is an example.

Comment: I am a bit confused about its usage. Where do I provide the _window handler_ (hwnd)? Do I need to use the `GetMesssage()` function before using the `GetMessagePos()`?

Comment: You can only retrieve windows that belong to the current thread.

Comment: So if I have an application (let's say paint), I have its `hwnd`, I moved the virtual mouse in paint via `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, I won't be able to get the virtual cursor in paint with just `hwnd`?

Comment: Yes, according to `GetMessage`: A handle to the window whose messages are to be retrieved. The window must belong to the current thread.So you can't get its internal messages only through hwnd.

Comment: I updated my question, to be more specific. I unfortunately am trying to get the virtual cursor position of an _external_ application, thus I have only its window handler.

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner I have updated my answer and you can refer to it.

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.